# list value replaced when set value to the sam object

Tags: java, list

list value replaced when I set value to another list.
please help me .

```
public void testValue(){
        invInTc1 = new ArrayList<>();
        invInTc2 = new ArrayList<>();

        InvInTc invIn = new InvInTc();
        invIn.setInvInTcKey("1234");
        invIn.setInvInTcQty(1); // I set value in here
        invInTc1.add(invIn);

        InvInTc invIn2 = invInTc1.get(0);
        invIn2.setInvInTcQty(5); // and when I set value again, value invInTc1 is replaced to 5
        invInTc2.add(invIn);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *one* object here - one instance of `InvInTc`.

The values in both array lists refer to the same object, so changes made to that object will be visible via both lists.

As a real world example, suppose I write down my home address on two pieces of paper, and give one piece of paper to Joe and one to Fred. Joe goes and paints my front door red... then Fred visits my house. Of course he'll see a red front door. Exactly the same thing is happening in your code.

If you want two independent objects, you need to *create* two independent objects:

```
InvInTc invIn = new InvInTc();
invIn.setInvInTcKey("1234");
invIn.setInvInTcQty(1);
invInTc1.add(invIn);

InvInTc invIn2 = new InvInTc();
// Copy the key from one object to the other
invIn2.setInvInTcKey(invIn.getInvTcKey());
// But set a different quantity
invIn2.setInvInTcQty(5);
invInTc2.add(invIn);
```

It's *vitally* important that you understand how objects and references work in Java. I strongly suggest you get hold of a good book which explains it in detail.

(I'd also encourage you to rethink your names to be more friendly.)

Comment: how I can copying values from invInTc1 to invInTc2 without having to set every attribute one by one?

Comment: @SanIrawan: You could create a constructor in `InvInTc` which takes an existing object and copies the values - then you only need to do it in one place. Or use `Object.clone()` potentially.

Answer (score 0):

The reference that you got using `invInTc1.get(0)` is still pointing to the same object which added in list1. So, when you modify the value, you are actually modifying the same object reference.

The changes made to this object will be visible to both the lists.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Arun, you are manipulating the same object, here is the dissection of your code:

InvInTc invIn = new InvInTc(); // you have created an instance here

// setting different attributes
   invIn.setInvInTcKey("1234");
   invIn.setInvInTcQty(1); // I set value in here

// adding the object to Arraylist
   invInTc1.add(invIn);

// You are creating a new reference which is pointing to the 0th element of the list
   // as you have added only one element i.e invIn so invIn2 will point to the same               // memory location as of invIn
   InvInTc invIn2 = invInTc1.get(0);

// so you are working on the same object but with your new reference hence the value will be changed to the same object as hold by invIn
  invIn2.setInvInTcQty(5);

//another element added to the list, but both the elements are referencing to the same object.
  invInTc2.add(invIn);

Hope it helps